# GOCD Job Level Environment Variable Interpolation

Tags: go-cd

On a job level environment variable configuration:

The following works when using parameters passed from another pipleline to my template:

Environment Variables

Name: BRANCH

Value:         #{PIPELINE_LEVEL_PARAMETER}_INDEX

However, this does not.

Name: BRANCH

Value:         ${STAGE_LEVEL_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}_INDEX

in the latter case, it takes the literal value without replacing with the environment variable